# Problems when migrating wordpress with All-in-One Migration

Tags: wordpress, migration

I try to migrate Wordpress from local to hosting using the All-in-One Migration plugin and the import starts but stalls at 0.04% and from there it doesn't progress.

I've tried using wifi or data connection and even a vpn.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [wordpress.se].